# Custom SnackBar Type Class for Reusability - flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

Hello, I'd love to know how to create a custom Class of **Type SnackBar** for reusability - so I can be allowed to use it in `ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar()` method that ONLY accepts **SnackBar type** & not StatelessWidget

---

I wanted a reusable SnackBar so I created this custom `SnackysnackBar` extending from `StatelessWidget`

```
class SnackysnackBar extends StatelessWidget {
  const SnackysnackBar({Key? key, required this.snackText}) : super(key: key);
  final String snackText;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => SnackBar(
    content: Text(
      '$snackText',
      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
    ),
    backgroundColor: Colors.green[300],
  );
}
```

thinking I would be able to reuse it in my :

```
ElevatedButton(
      onPressed: () {
        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackysnackBar(snackText: "I'm a snack Text look at me"));
      },
```

turns out it only accepts a `parameter of type 'SnackBar'`

- so I thought I would extend a class from [SnackBar](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/SnackBar-class.html) like this right ?

```
class SnackysnackBar extends SnackBar {
  final String snackText;
  
const SnackysnackBar({Key? key, required this.snackText,}) : super(key: key, this.content,);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => SnackBar(
        content: Text(
          '$snackText',
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
        ),
        backgroundColor: Colors.green[300],
      );
}
```

but it seems like it's not the right approach - or is it ?

---

I'm getting this error : "The named parameter 'content' is required, but there's no corresponding argument."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got inspired by the answer given by [happy-san](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68397450/12072012). I came with this structured way.
Create a separate file for alerts. I named it alert_utils.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Alert {
  BuildContext context;

  Alert.of(this.context);

  // show an error message
  void showError(String message) {
    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
      SnackBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.red,
        content: Text(
          message,
          style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  // show an error message
  void showSuccess(String message) {
    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
      SnackBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.green,
        content: Text(
          message,
          style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

You can add more message types as your need.

Now instead of this,

```
ElevatedButton(
      onPressed: () {
        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(getSnackBar("I'm a snack Text look at me"));
      }
      ...
)
```

Do this,

```
ElevatedButton(
    onPressed: () {
         Alert.of(context).showSuccess("I'm a snack Text look at me");
    }
    ...
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply create a function

```dart
SnackBar getSnackBar(String snackText) => SnackBar(
      content: Text(
        '$snackText',
        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
      ),
      backgroundColor: Colors.green[300],
    );
```

and pass it around

```dart
ElevatedButton(
      onPressed: () {
        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(getSnackBar("I'm a snack Text look at me"));
      },
```

Comment: Very smart indeed ! I'm learning so much every day thks to this community ! Thank you, I hope I can give back as much very soon !